# Deleting words that lack a specific character in a string?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a use case where I want to delete every word in a string that doesn't have a period in the middle of it. Can someone provide a solution and if willing, provide an explanation of how it works please?

String Example:

```
Testy.mctestface 1337 taco
```

Desired Result:

```
Testy.mctestface
```

Comment: Try to think of positive, not negative, ways to express your requirements. `I want to delete every word in a string that doesn't have a period in the middle of it` is much simpler and clearer as `I want to print every word in a string that has a period in the middle`. You'd be amazed how often negatively-written requirements end up with negatively (or double -negatively!) written code that's buggier and/or much harder to understand than it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -oE '\w+\.\w+'
```

`\w+` - Matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
`+` -  Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
`\.` - Matches the character `.` literally (case sensitive)

The `-o` option for `grep` says to return **only** the match, the `-E` option allows extended regex.

This will essentially match any word or combination of words that contain a period.

```
$ echo 'foo bar Testy.mctestface 1337 taco' | grep -oE '\w+\.\w+'
Testy.mctestface
```

---

If your word can contain special characters you could use something like:

```
grep -oE '\S+\.\S+'
```

The `\S+` will match any non-whitespace character one to unlimited times.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Jesse. That explanation was very helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
sed '
  s/.*/ & /
  :1
    s/ [^ .]\{1,\} / /g
  t1
  s/^ //;s/ $//'
```

Comment: Any reason for using ```\{1,\}``` instead of ```\+```?

Comment: @G-Man, `\{1,\}` is standard, `\+` is a GNU extension.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you annotate your this `sed` code so others can understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides [grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531910/117549) or [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531912/117549), you could use `awk`:

```
{
  for(i=1; i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /\./)
                out=out" "$i
  print out
  out=""
}
```

... to save in a file and run via `awk -f thatfile input1 input2...`, or:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /\./) out=out" "$i; print out; out="" }' input
```

... to put the script on the command-line.

Awk automatically splits each line of input for you, based on spaces (the default value of its special `FS` variable). The script loops through each resulting field of that split and runs a test: if the value of that field contains a period (escaped, because period is a special token in regular expressions), then append that field (with a space) to a new string that we'll output at the end. This has the effect of skipping over fields that don't contain a period.  Once the loop through the fields is complete, we print that reconstructed value (in `out`) and reset it to the empty string, in case there are more lines in the input.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler version of the `awk` answer:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /\./) $i = ""; print; }'
```

For each word, if it *doesn’t* contain a dot, clobber it. 
Then print what’s left.

---

On rereading the question, I see that it says
“every word … that doesn’t have a period *in **the middle** of it*.” 
So, for example, the input

```
Mr. Smith ate .5 pies in New York.
```

should produce no output,
because there is no word that has a period *in the middle.* 
By contrast,

```
Mr.Smith ate 1.5 pies in New York.
```

should report `Mr.Smith` and `1.5`. 
So the command should be

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i !~ /.\../) $i = ""; print; }'
```

For each word, if it *doesn’t* contain a period,
with at least one other character before it and after it, clobber the word.